# HTML PHP FORM NOT SENDING EMAIL

Tags: php, html, forms, email, submit

my HTML / PHP  website does not send email from form. It is saying thank you but mail is not recieved. Why? please help!

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Contact No: $number \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "umair.bpd@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Contact form from website";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

```
<form id="contact-form" action="submitform.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <input name="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <input name="number"  type="text" placeholder="Contact No.">
    <textarea name="message"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thats in your question is it not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: What error do you get?
On what server are you running it?
Do you use an email service?

Comment: It shows Thank You as the final message. but mail isn't recieved

Comment: Have you configured a mail server on your server?

Comment: Use mailtrap (https://mailtrap.io/) to trap your emails to see if you get them. If you're getting them in mailtrap but not through your mail server then your mail server isn't set up correctly.

Comment: If your server is correctly configured, it's possible that your webhost is blocking mails, or GMail temporarily refuses to receive from your host (happens easily if sites on from your IP send bulk mail, incl. convey form spam or other forwarded spam). See your mail logs for relevant information.